# Как правильно написать метод для обновления записи в базе, чтобы он возвращал объект?

Tags: hibernate, java

Как переделать метод, чтобы он возвращал тип Competition?

```
public Competition updateCompetition(Long id, Integer point, Integer place){
            Query q = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("update Competition set point= :point, place= :place where id = :id");
            q.setParameter("id", id);
            q.setParameter("point", point);
            q.setParameter("place", place);
            return (Competition) q.executeUpdate();//так не приводит типы
        }
```

Comment: Вам обязательно использовать HQL? Или можно предложить способ попроще?

Comment: Нужно делать еще один селект с переданным id.

Comment: да, нужно HQL.

Comment: Такой селект делать?

 
    public Competition retriveCompById(Long id){
            Query q = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Competition where id = :id");
            q.setLong("id", id);
            return (Competition) q.uniqueResult();
        }